# Compute laplacian using gradient

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, computer-vision, convolution

I'm trying to get Laplacian using 3 different method, in case 1 and 2 results the same but what is wrong with 3?

Here is code in Matlab:

```
m= magic(6)

Lap1Dx= convn(m,[-1 2 -1],'same')
Lap1Dy= convn(m,[-1;2;-1],'same')

%ver1
Lap2Dxy= convn(m,[0 -1 0;-1 4 -1;0 -1 0],'same')

%ver2
Lap2Dxy= Lap1Dx+Lap1Dy %same as ver 1

%ver 3
%get laplacian using gradients
gradx= convn(m,[-1 1],'same')
grady= convn(m,[-1;1],'same')

gradxx= convn(gradx,[-1 1],'same')
gradyy= convn(grady,[-1;1],'same')

Lap2Dxy= gradxx+gradyy
```

Output:

```
m =

   35    1    6   26   19   24
    3   32    7   21   23   25
   31    9    2   22   27   20
    8   28   33   17   10   15
   30    5   34   12   14   16
    4   36   29   13   18   11

Lap1Dx =

   69  -39  -15   27  -12   29
  -26   54  -39   12    0   27
   53  -15  -27   15   12   13
  -12   15   21   -9  -12   20
   55  -54   51  -24    0   18
  -28   39    9  -21   12    4

Lap1Dy =

   67  -30    5   31   15   23
  -60   54    6   -6    0    6
   51  -42  -36    6   21    0
  -45   42   30    0  -21   -6
   48  -54    6   -6    0    6
  -22   67   24   14   22    6

Lap2Dxy =

   136   -69   -10    58     3    52
   -86   108   -33     6     0    33
   104   -57   -63    21    33    13
   -57    57    51    -9   -33    14
   103  -108    57   -30     0    24
   -50   106    33    -7    34    10

Lap2Dxy =

   136   -69   -10    58     3    52
   -86   108   -33     6     0    33
   104   -57   -63    21    33    13
   -57    57    51    -9   -33    14
   103  -108    57   -30     0    24
   -50   106    33    -7    34    10

gradx =

   34   -5  -20    7   -5   24
  -29   25  -14   -2   -2   25
   22    7  -20   -5    7   20
  -20   -5   16    7   -5   15
   25  -29   22   -2   -2   16
  -32    7   16   -5    7   11

grady =

   32  -31   -1    5   -4   -1
  -28   23    5   -1   -4    5
   23  -19  -31    5   17    5
  -22   23   -1    5   -4   -1
   26  -31    5   -1   -4    5
    4   36   29   13   18   11

gradxx =

   39   15  -27   12  -29   24
  -54   39  -12    0  -27   25
   15   27  -15  -12  -13   20
  -15  -21    9   12  -20   15
   54  -51   24    0  -18   16
  -39   -9   21  -12   -4   11

gradyy =

   60  -54   -6    6    0   -6
  -51   42   36   -6  -21    0
   45  -42  -30    0   21    6
  -48   54   -6    6    0   -6
   22  -67  -24  -14  -22   -6
    4   36   29   13   18   11

Lap2Dxy =

    99   -39   -33    18   -29    18
  -105    81    24    -6   -48    25
    60   -15   -45   -12     8    26
   -63    33     3    18   -20     9
    76  -118     0   -14   -40    10
   -35    27    50     1    14    22
```

Comment: It my have something to do on how you are calculating the derivatives. You are using backward finite differences, try with others (I cannot run Matlab now).

Comment: @AnderBiguri you mean [1 -1] instead of [-1 1]?

Comment: or `[-1 0 1]`, or any of the possible versions that you could find of the discrete approximation of a derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there are some sign issues. Convolving with [-1 1] gives you the first derivative with the minus sign: convolution flips one of two arrays so you end subtracting each element from the following one. Convolve with [1 -1] to get the first derivative. For the second derivative, use [1 -2 1].

But the main issue here has to do with truncation ('same' parameter). With the first two approaches, you convolve and then truncate. With the third, you convolve, then truncate, then convolve again and truncate again.

Since the issue can be seen already on a one-dimensional array, I'll focus on the first row of yours. Let's drop the parameter `same` for now:

```
m = [35    1    6   26   19   24]
mx = convn(m,[1 -1])        //  [35 -34   5  20  -7   5  -24]
mxx = convn(mx,[1 -1])      //  [35 -69  39  15 -27  12  -29  24]
m2x = convn(m,[1 -2 1])     //  [35 -69  39  15 -27  12  -29  24]
```

As you can see, the results are identical. Next, with the 'same' parameter:

```
mx = convn(m,[1 -1],'same')        //  [-34   5  20  -7   5  -24]
mxx = convn(mx,[1 -1],'same')      //  [39  15  -27  12 -29  24]
m2x = convn(m,[1 -2 1],'same')     //  [-69  39  15 -27  12  -29]
```

For m2x, 'same' cleanly picks the middle part of the full convolution, which is  exactly the part you want.

But for the first-order derivative, there is just one element to drop. The choice has to be made, and convn drops the first one (resulting in the forward difference). When computing mxx, it has to do it **again**. So, as a result of dropping the first element of full convolution twice, you end up with a shifted array. This is why mxx has most of the same numbers as m2x, except misaligned.

---

If you insist on having two-step convolution (first derivative, then second), the first convolution must be without any truncation. Otherwise, the truncation influences the result of the second convolution. For the second one, you can use 'same' but in addition, the last element will need to be dropped. Like this.

```
 mx = convn(m, [1 -1])
 mxx = convn(mx,[1 -1],'same')
 mxx = mxx(1:end-1)
```

Or, equivalently,

```
 mx = convn(m, [1 -1])
 mxx = convn(mx,[1 -1])
 mxx = mxx(2:end-1)
```

Comment: what about 2D case? if I drop "same" then Lap1Dx and Lap1Dy have different size and I can't add them.

Comment: I didn't mean you should drop 'same'. I tried to explain why the first two methods give a correct result while the third doesn't: because of asymmetrical truncation.

Comment: I understand your point, but I can't understand how to fix it, what part of result I should take instead of center part as 'same' does?

Comment: See the part added after the separator. (That said, I don't know why you want to do it this way: generally the second derivatives works _better_ than the first derivative in discrete setting. Going directly for the second derivative makes perfect sense.)

Comment: Because I need to change gradient field, so I need this intermediate step of computing gradient.